# Mysql DATETIME evaluation: Get all records whose value is before midnight of the current day (basically yesterday and before

Tags: mysql

This is really simple yet I always struggle with it. I need help getting records before midnight:

```
 AND last_checked < date('2013-06-25 00:00:00'))
```

This obviously doesn't work, since its string evaluation. I do not want to restrict it to this year and put a between in the code. Any help is extremely appreciated :)

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do. Can you post whole query please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can also do this in a generic way

```
AND last_checked < ( DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND );
```

Watch this:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND Midnight;
+---------------------+
| Midnight            |
+---------------------+
| 2013-06-25 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just do

```
AND last_checked < '2013-06-25 00:00:00'
```

Using the `date()` function just extracts the date part of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

If `last_checked` is of `datetime` data type, then your `WHERE` clause will look like this:

```
WHERE ... 
    AND cast (last_checked as date) = '2013-06-25'
```

`CAST (datetime as date)` drops time part, so you can easily get all data between 00h:00m:00s and 23h:59m:59s .